# How can i have clickable URLs in Conemu?

Tags: windows, conemu

I just had a message from Ruby saying

```
C:\Users\ndx>gem install awestruct
Fetching: hpricot-0.8.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing awestruct:
        The 'hpricot' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Why aren't those URLs clickable ? (would be way cool to have such a feature in terminal).

Answer (score 34):

Hold <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd> and click them.

Look for "Highlight & goto" option on "Controls" page ("Mark & Paste" in old stable release).

Comment: I was thinking so because they were not highlighted, even when hoverring on them (but I must confess I was quite sure they would be, given the quality of Conemu).

Comment: Thought, Ctrl+Click is often used in misc programs for hyperlinks. And url "detecting" on each mouse move (without Ctrl) will be redundant. Thats why "LeftCtrl" is set be default. But user may change or remove "key-modifier".

Answer (score 0):

> *Quoting the "credits" link contents partially*
>
> ConEmu can highlight hyperlinks (e.g. http://www.farmanager.com) and compiler errors (e.g. FarCtrl.pas(1002,49) Error: Identifier not found...).
>
> Turn on checkbox «Highlight and goto» and choose appropriate modifier (e.g. «Left Ctrl») on the TextSelection page. So, when you hold selected modifier (e.g. «Left Ctrl») ConEmu will underlines hyperlinks/errors detected under mouse cursor. LeftClick (with modifier) will open it:
>
> hyperlinks - in the default browser
>
> e-mails - in the default Mail program
>
> compiler errors - in the Far editor, positioned on row and column of the error

[Credits](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/UsingMouse)

Comment: That TextSelection page is available on which Conemu version ? I'm using latest stable (`120916`) and can't find that option.

Comment: Current 'stable' is 120727c. So, x916 is alpha, not stable and not latest. Option located on 'Mark & Paste' page (regardless of version).

Comment: @Maximus then how can I have used that version (I'm really puzzled as I don't remember having downloaded an alpha version) ?

Comment: I can't suggest where and what version you have downloaded ;)